# want to autowire DAO class in my entity class

Tags: spring

i have a method which i need to call in my entity class company.java.
but when i run my application it throws null pointer exception didn't fount that DAO object in entity class..

How can i get that object in entity class please help

This is my entity class..

```
package com.salebuild.model;

/**
 * Define a company.
 *
 * @author mseritan
 */
@Entity
@Table(name = "company", uniqueConstraints = {@UniqueConstraint(columnNames = "name")})
@XmlRootElement
@XmlSeeAlso(value = ArrayList.class)
public class Company implements PublishableIF, Serializable, PersistableIF, HistoryIF, AddressableIF {
     private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger( Company.class );
     @Autowired
        private CompanyDAO companyDAO;

    // CONSTANTS -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    // ATTRIBUTES ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    private Long id;
    @NotBlank
    private String name;
    private String formerName;
    private CorporateTitle topLevelExec;
    private List<CompanySite> sites;
    private List<CompanyAlias> aliases;
    @NotNull
    private Industry industry;
    private Company parentCompany;
    private String emailTopology;
    @NotNull
    private Double revenue;

    @NotNull
    private Long numberEmployees;
    private CustomerType.Type customerType;
    private Boolean recruiter = false;
    private int publishState;
    private CompanyStatus status;
    private Boolean excludeCompany = false;
    private CompanyType companyType;
    private String salesifyCompanyId;
    private CompanySiteType companySiteType;
    private String websiteUrl;
    private String sourceVendor;
    private String notes;
    private List<CompanySpecializedRanking> specializedList = new ArrayList<CompanySpecializedRanking>();
    @NotNull
    private NAICSCode naicsCode;
    @NotNull
    private SICCode sicCode;
    private Long version;
    private List<Technology> technologies = new ArrayList<Technology>();
    private List<CompanyContact> contacts;
    private String phoneNumber;
    private String faxNumber;
    private String email;

    private User userCreated;
    private Date dateCreated;

    private User userLastModified;
    private Date dateLastModified;

    private User userLastResearcher;
    private Date dateLastResearcher;
    @NotBlank
    private String street1;
    private String street2;
    private String street3;
    private String city;
    private String zipCode;
    private State state;
    private Country country;
    private String specRankingListName;
    private Integer specRankingRank;
    private Integer specRankingYear;
    private String modifiedCompanyName;

    private String formattedRevenue;
    private String formattedEmployeeSize;
    private List<JobPostingRaw> unconfirmedTechnologies;
    // ACESSORS ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   //getter setter for other fields //
        this.specRankingYear = specRankingYear;
    }


    /**
     * @param modifiedCompanyName  
     *
     */
    @Column(name="modifiedCompanyName")
    public String getModifiedCompanyName() {
        return modifiedCompanyName;
    }

    public void setModifiedCompanyName(String modifiedCompanyName) {
        if(modifiedCompanyName==null)
            this.modifiedCompanyName=modifiedCompanyName;
        else{
         this.modifiedCompanyName =companyDAO.updateCompanyName(modifiedCompanyName);
        }
    }

    @Transient
    public List<JobPostingRaw> getUnconfirmedTechnologies() {
        return unconfirmedTechnologies;
    }

    public void setUnconfirmedTechnologies(
            List<JobPostingRaw> unconfirmedTechnologies) {
        this.unconfirmedTechnologies = unconfirmedTechnologies;
    }



}
```

my DAO class is like that --

```
package com.salebuild.dao;

import com.salebuild.model.Company;
import com.salebuild.model.search.EntitySearchCriteria;
import com.salebuild.model.search.SortedResultsPage;

import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Set;

public interface CompanyDAO extends CrudDAO<Company> {
    Company findByNameOrAlias(String name);

    List<Company> findBySearchTerm(String searchTerm, Integer start, Integer count);

   // SortedResultsPage<Company> findPaged(EntitySearchCriteria criteria);

    List<Long> findIds(EntitySearchCriteria criteria);

    List<Company> find(Collection<Long> ids);

    /**
     * For just finding the company name and not looking for alias names.
     *
     * @param name
     * @return
     */
    public Company findByName( String name );
    public Company findByModifiedName(String name,Company... c);

    public int companyCountSinceLastLogin(Long id);

    Set<Long> findDistinctIds(EntitySearchCriteria criteria);

    public Integer getCompanyCountByRegion(Long regionId,List techCatIds);

    List<Company> findAllCompanies(Company instance);

    public List<Company> findAllModifiedCompanies(Company instance);

    public String updateCompanyName(String name);
}
```

Comment: This is bad design. Why are you injecting the DAO within your Entity class?

Comment: i need to call a sql function in my dao class to set modifiedcompnyname . please suggest any other way for doing this

Comment: @shitanshu could you please modify your question to your real needs? also, why dont you simply invoque your function inside a method from the dao via a `createNativeQuery`

Comment: I need to call this setter method everytime the object is saved.So I want to put call it in a setter method So that its called everytime the object is modified or created.

Comment: @dimitrisli, are you familiar with Active Records?

Answer (score 2):

The easiest option is to implement factory for building entities. Then you can use AutowireCapableBeanFactory to autowire dependencies:

```
public abstract class GenericFactory<T> {

  @Autowired
  private AutowireCapableBeanFactory autowireBeanFactory;

  public T createBean() {
    // creation logic
    autowireBeanFactory.autowireBean(createdBean);
    return createdBean;
  }
}
```

Of course you can pass object (created or retrieved) and just autowire it.

Another option is to use @Configurable - it automatically injects dependencies. http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html#aop-atconfigurable

You can find more details in my post: http://www.kubrynski.com/2013/09/injecting-spring-dependencies-into-non.html

Answer (score 0):

JPA entities are meant to be POJOs i.e. simple Java beans which do not have dependencies and have getters and setters which contain no complex logic.

It would be better to create a service which is responsible for saving and updating your entity which is used throughout your code. This service can then be responsible for executing the logic you wish to put in your setter using dependencies which can be autowired.

The issue you have is that you Spring is not responsible for the creation of your entity. You either instantiate it using `new` or you obtain it from your JPA implementation. Either way there is no opportunity for Spring to autowire declared dependencies.

---

As an aside it's not good practice to autowire private variables. See this [blog post](http://olivergierke.de/2013/11/why-field-injection-is-evil/) for a fuller discussion.

Comment: I think this depends, some kind of Active Records entity are useful in Domain Driven Design.

Comment: Autowiring private variables in service is bad idea, but in entity this is proper way :)

Comment: You should read about Domain Driven Design - there all business logic is stored in entities, and described by yourself "anemic entities" are treated as an antipattern

Comment: I think `anemic entities` and service inside entity are different things ;) You can have rich entity without service injected.

Comment: If you're loading an entity from your JPA provider the only way to autowire dependencies is to provide static access to your injector/bean store. This doesn't sound like a good idea to me and is the opposite of dependency injection.

Comment: How would that work if you're calling load on a session to obtain your entity?

Comment: @Alex why do you want to obtain entity in this entity?